# Loading a block from code and define the layout around?

Tags: magento, layout

I am creating a block in my code from a controller:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template', 'some_name', array('template' => 'catalog/product/view/somephtml.phtml'));
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
$this->renderLayout();
```

This works fine, the content of the phtml is shown. Thing is, its shown in a 3-column layout in the center column. I want only the right column and no left column. How can I define that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->setTemplate('page/2columns-right.phtml')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am setting another template already, do I have to define this custom template to have only one column?